# how to analyze Android(AOSP) build performance?

Tags: android, build, android-source, ninja, android-profiler

I wanted to do a profiling of the AOSP build process and identify bottlenecks and see how to accelerate the build process. I'm working on `Android Pie` which comes with prebuilt `ninja` build system, there is a preliminary [visualization tool](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools) ("-t"), other than that, is there any profiler tool to analyze the build process like [this one for Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/perf.md)